# git EOL converted the opposit way around? (despite .gitattributes)

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, eol, gitattributes

I am working on Windows 7 and to prevent EOL problems I have a `.gitattributes` file set up the following way (as described in the [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)):

```
* text=auto

*.js text
```

But now, when I commit a `js`-file that has only `LF` line-endings I get the warning:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in XXX.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Well, this sounds to me like I will have `CRLF` in my repository and `LF` in my working directory, even though it should be (and I want it to be) the exact other way around. The `js`-file's line endings are still `LF` after the commit.

Am I reading the warning wrong or did I set up `.gitattributes` in the wrong way?
Thanks!

p.s. my global git config has `autocrlf = true`, but that should not effect the EOL-conversion when committing because of the `.gitattributes` file

p.p.s the `js` file is in a subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable `autocrlf` – It is not causing this “situation”, but it *does* collide with the gitattributes setting and adds no benefits.

You don’t have any problem with EOL conversion in your repo. The message you quoted is telling you, that if you check out this file again (with these settings), you will have CRLF in your working directory. But for now it will stay at LF.

If you want to know what line endings stuff has in your repo, run this:

```
git show commit:path/to/file | file -k -
```

If you want to get rid of that message, set your editor to save files with CRLF. Or better: If all your tools support LF endings, set this repo to use LF on checkout (if you accidentally save a file with CRLF, it will still be normalized):

```
git config core.eol lf
```

*Note:* this will probably only work if you set `core.autocrlf` to `false`

Comment: What problems does autocrlf have?  It is helpful when your cloning something random on the net to a windows machine.

Comment: You can do `git config core.eol lf` but without modifying local variables with `* text eol=lf` which is the .gitattributes way. I don't see the advantage of the OP going back to variables for text filtering settings (specially if he's mixing it with the new way (`.gitattributes`) as well).

Comment: @sabgenton One of the problems with autocrlf is that people different people checking out the same repo will have different settings. So you will get commits that seemingly change the whole file. If you cloned something from the internet and think the line endings on windows are wrong, you should add a `.gitattributes` file. If you are sure you are never going to commit and thus don’t want to create a `.gitattributes`, you can just use the `.git/info/attributes` file.

Answer (score 1):

Git is doing exactly what you want to spite its badly worded warning you don't have to change anything (that warning only talks about the what is happening to the working directory AFAIK not the database).

LF will be in the repo only, if you rm the file and check it out again it will be converted to CRLF in the working tree (only).

I have seen people say don't change local core settings/global variables when it comes to line endings ([article](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) git hub refer to) (I don't see a conflict with autocrlf) and only use .gitattribute because it makes defaults for the projects your working in, it's the newer way.

If you want stuff to be LF only you should use a different git attributes line but stick with what you got for your original question it's fine.  (The [docs page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) and your [github](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) page seems to say `text eol=lf` if you want LF only)

*This is a necropost just to say don't worry it's sposed to say that :)*